# I want to fetch data from the database using useeffect but it isnt working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View ,TextInput ,Button,Text} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
// Initialize Firebase
let app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const db = app.database();


function App() { 
  const[message,setMessage]=useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      db.ref().child("messages").once("value",
          snapshot=>{
              const data=snapshot.val()
              if(snapshot.val()){
                  const initMessages=[];
                  Object.
                  keys(data).
                  forEach(message=>initMessages.push(data[message]));
                  ()=>setMessages([initMessages]);    
             }  
          }
      )
      db.ref().child("messages").on("child_added",
          snapshot=>{
              const data=snapshot.val()
              if(snapshot.val()){
                 (prevMessages)=> setMessages([data,...prevMessages]);
                  }
              }
      )
  })

  const addItem =()=>{
      if(!message) return;
      const newMessage=db.ref().child("messages").push();
      newMessage.set(message,()=>setMessage(''));

  }
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.messageBox}>
            <TextInput placeholder=" enter text message" style={styles.textInput}
            value={message} onChangeText={text=>setMessage(text)}/>
            <Button title="send" onPress={addItem}/>
          </View> 
          <FlatList data={messages}
            renderItem={({item})=>
            <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.listItem}>{item}</Text>
            </View>}
            />
        </View>
      )
  }

  export default App;
```

additem is working correctly by adding data to the database but useEffect part isnt working.Which is used to fetch data from the db .

1. possible error would be that I am not using useState properly.
2. some syntax error in useEffect block

description of code- It is a messageboard application with fetch data from db and also write data in db when input is given

Comment: I think that you should use **async** and **await** to make sure that the data loaded before you print it.

Comment: @besartm can you specify where should put them for the code to work?

Comment: I really dont have much time to test your code but, in my case I would create a function inside useEffect() - the function should have **async** and whenever you fetch data from database you use **await**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      db.ref().child("messages").once("value",
          snapshot=>{
              const data=snapshot.val()
              if(snapshot.val()){
                  const initMessages=[];
                  Object.
                  keys(data).
                  forEach(message=>initMessages.push(data[message]));
                  //()=>setMessages([initMessages]); 
                  //you need to call the function setMessages not define it   
                  setMessages([initMessages])
 }  
          }
      )
      db.ref().child("messages").on("child_added",
          snapshot=>{
              const data=snapshot.val()

//double check your data here
              if(snapshot.val()){
                 (prevMessages)=> setMessages([data,...prevMessages]);
                  }
              }
      )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

On my case I have build a hook which I have been used whenever I made request from database. Here I just take an example:

```
const App = () =>{
      const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() =>{
            try {
                const response = await fetchSomeData();
                setData(response);
            } catch (err) {}
        };
        fetchData();
    },[]);

    .
    .
    .

    return(
        <div>...</div>
    );
}
```